Is there a special way to import a QML file from a QRC resource file?
I'm working on a small app and I'm having difficulty importing a QML file from a QRC resource file.
My QRC is as follows:
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/qml">
        <file alias="ProductionPane">qml/view/ProductionPane.qml</file>
        <file alias="SideBar">qml/view/SideBar.qml</file>
        <file alias="TestingView">qml/view/TestingView.qml</file>
        <file alias="LogView">qml/view/LogView.qml</file>
        <file alias="StatsView">qml/view/StatsView.qml</file>
        <file alias="MyButton">qml/comp/MyButton.qml</file>
    </qresource>
    <qresource prefix="/assets">
        <file alias="Logo">assets/img/logo.png</file>
    </qresource>
    <qresource prefix="/">
        <file>main.qml</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>

The files are "physically" organized in the following manner:
main.qml
main.py
rc_resources.py

qml/view/LogView.qml
qml/view/ProductionPane.qml
qml/view/SideBar.qml
qml/view/StatsView.qml
qml/view/TestingView.qml

qml/comp/MyButton.qml

assets/img/logo.png

Here's my main.py file:
import sys
from pathlib import Path

from PySide6.QtGui import QGuiApplication
from PySide6.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine
from PySide6.QtCore import QUrl

import rc_resources

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)
    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
    
    engine.addImportPath("qrc:/view")

    engine.load(QUrl("qrc:/main.qml"))

    if not engine.rootObjects():
        sys.exit(-1)
    sys.exit(app.exec())

And finally, my main.qml file:
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Window
import QtQuick.Controls

import "qrc:/qml/ProductionPane"
import "qml/view"

Window {
    id: mainWindow
    minimumWidth: 1024
    minimumHeight: 768
    width: 1920
    height: 1080
    title: qsTr("FooBar")

    ProductionPane {
        id: productionPane
        anchors.fill: parent
    }

    SideBar {
        onViewChanged: productionPane.loaderSource = view
    }
}

Without import "qml/view" in main.qml, the ProductionPane and SideBar objects aren't recognized in QT creator.
I verified (in main.py after instantiation of the QQmlApplicationEngine object) that QFileInfo(":/qml/ProductionPane").exists() returns true, so I know that the engine can find the QML file in the QRC file, but importing it isn't working, as I'm getting the following error when running it:
qrc:/main.qml:4:1: "qrc:/qml/ProductionPane": no such directory

I get this error when I use "qrc:/qml/ProductionPane".
":/qml/ProductionPane" results in an IDE error File or directory not found.
Does anyone have any suggestions?
Thanks!

AFAIK, you can't just import a single file; you should import its parent directory.

Unfortunately, I get more-or-less the same error when I attempt to import "qrc:qml/view/".

You also cannot use qrc in the import path.

@smr, I'm pretty sure you can, though. After further fiddling around with it, I realized that my structure in the QRC file was adding additional "structure" to the path for each file in the QRC. After changing "qrc:/qml/view/" to "qrc:/qml/qml/view", the application ran. Unfortunately, Qt Creator doesn't recognize components in those files unless I also import "./qml/view" from the file system. But this throws a execution error, because that import is being called from a QRC context and it can't find the directory.

Does this answer your question? How can I organize files under the qml.qrc folder in Qt Creator?
